# I'm disabling cookies on firefox, while adding exceptions, but I still have issues

Tags: firefox, cookies, web, gmail, privacy

I added google.com, *.google.com and battlelog.battlefield.com and I still encounter issues with them. For example gmail can't connect to the google chat thing, google drive says it encountered an error, and the battlefield app is just not launching battlefield 3. I have to reenable cookies with some addon button to overcome the issue.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? What is the problem there? Does disabling cookie systemically break websites and prevent them from working?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use * in cookies exceptions anymore. You must add http://google.com and https://google.com for this.

Comment: `https://accounts.google.com` works as well, in case you want to be a bit more specific.